# Некоторые элементы из списка преобразовать в int

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли более короткий способ для преобразование элементов в тип `int`?
Дан, например, список `a = ["1", "2", "привет", "3", "привет"]`
Можно ли, как-то короче все это преобразование записать, но не так:

```
a[0] = int(a[0])
a[1] = int(a[1])
a[3] = int(a[3])
```

Список в действительности длиннее, не хочется в коде такой столб делать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проходим в цикле по каждому элементу и пытаемся конвертировать его в целое число. Если получается - присваиваем элементу, если нет, сообщаем (или нет) и переходим к следующему элементу.

```
a = ["1", "2", "привет", "3", "привет"]
for index in range(len(a)):
    try:
        a[index] = int(a[index])
    except ValueError:
        print("not a number") # или что угодно, pass, например
print(a)
```

Результат:

```
> not a number
> not a number
> [1, 2, 'привет', 3, 'привет']
```

Comment: Дополнение для автора вопроса (ну, на всякий случай). Если при обнаружении не числа не нужно ничего выводить, вместо `print("not a number")` просто напишите `pass`

Comment: @Евгений Да, в комментарии написал.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [int(x) if x.lstrip('-').isdecimal() else x for x in a]
```

Comment: хм. "вот это поворот!"

Comment: А что отличный ответ, но не мой ;). Пометил как общий

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5225/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83

Comment: да на здоровье.

Comment: Кстати, стоп. Косяк: https://ideone.com/r20mOJ. // cc @strawdog

Comment: @Qwertiy ну, это не косяк, это предсказуемое поведение метода. стрипы в питоне  - greedy operators.

Comment: @strawdog, согласен, что предсказуемое, но всё же код-то отработает неверно на таких данных, так что это предсказуемый косяк ;)

Answer (score 3):

https://ideone.com/o3LBgj

```
a = ["1", "2", "привет", "3", "привет", "123", "1e2", "-9", "-3007", "-9.7"]
a = [int(x) if x.isdigit() or x[0]=='-' and x[1:].isdigit() else x for x in a]
print(a)
```

```
[1, 2, 'привет', 3, 'привет', 123, '1e2', -9, -3007, '-9.7']
```

Comment: `a = [int(x) if x.lstrip('-').isdecimal() else x for x in a]`

Comment: @strawdog, мне кажется, это надо постить отдельным ответом. UPDATE: Хм.. уже запостили.

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать функцию, пытающуюся преобразовать в `int`:

```py
def try_to_int(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value
```

А затем:

```py
list(map(try_to_int, a))
```

Comment: list надо куда-то сохранить, а то пропадёт бесследно.