# Ввести в 1 строку несколько значений разних типов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть пременные а, р, о, надо ввести их в 1 строку с разными типами данных.
Типа так:

```
а, р, о = map(int, input().split())
```

Ввод:

```
4.6 45 -7.373
```

Вывод:

```
4.6 45 -7.373
```

Но у меня выходит ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/KWDOD.py", line 1, in <module>
    q, w, e = map(int, input().split())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.6'
```

Comment: int - целочисленный тип данных, и не может содержать дроби (4.6)

Comment: Переменная a должна быть типом float()

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться ответами из вопроса [Некоторые элементы из списка преобразовать в int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059473/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-int).

Answer (score 1):

Если вас правильно понял, 2 варианта ниже.
Но так делать не безопасно.

```
from typing import Any
from decimal import Decimal


def auto_type(n: Any):
    try:
        quantize = Decimal("123.456") # Тут кол-во знаков после запятой указывать
        n = Decimal(float(n)).quantize(quantize).normalize()
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return n


def auto_type(n: Any):
    try:
        n = float(n)
        if str(n % 1)[2:] == "0":
            n = int(n)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return n


text = "4.6 45 -7.373"
q, w, e = map(auto_type, text.split(" "))
print(q, w, e)
print(*map(type, (q, w, e)))
```

Вывод:

```
4.6 45 -7.373
<class 'float'> <class 'int'> <class 'float'>
```